# Knockout.js how do I move my data-bind into a function in the head?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have a data-bind that has a lot of logic in it. Currently I have to paste it several places to get what I want. I would like to be able to make it a function that is only in one place preferably as a method of the KO object. The data-bind I need to move is the one that creates the italicized count text.

```
data-bind="text: ($data.children)?($data.children.filter(function(e){return e.enabled()}).length + ' Children On'):('No Children')"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5UeND/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function on your main viewmodel which returns a `ko.computed` with the calculation:

```
self.childrenCounter = function(data) {
        return ko.computed(function() {
            return (this.children) ? (this.children.filter(function(e) {
                return e.enabled()
            }).length + ' Children On') : ('No Children')
        }, data);
    }
```

Then you can use like this inside in your template:

```
<i data-bind="text: $root.childrenCounter($data)"></i>
```

[Demo JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/Gqd9c/)

Comment: Why were you able to pass $data like that? That is what I wanted to do but it kept blowing up!

Comment: @Tom I don't really following you... `$data` is special [context property](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html) . It is the view model object in the current context what you can pass into any function on the view model. What do you mean on "kept blowing up"?

Comment: I think I understand now. I kept trying to pass $data directly to a ko.computed() You used a wrapper function to pass it. I also don't think I used the correct second argument for ko.computed.